# How do I make pseudo-element scale with the image?

Tags: css, image, sass, responsive-design, pseudo-element

I have an `img` element that is in the `div` box which has a pseudo-element (namely `::before`) on it. I now would like to make that image scale the same way as the pseudo-element. So that the pseudo stays in the same position as it is placed right now (where the screen width is 375px). No idea how to do it. Could someone please help me?

```
<div class="image-box">
    <img class="image-box__image" src="assets/image.png">
</div>
```

```
.image-box {
    position: relative;
    &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 8.25em;
        height: 8.25em;
        background: tomato;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: calc(50% - 4.5em);
        top: -5px;
    }
    &__image {
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%); 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you link an image of what you would like ?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard Does it really matter? :D Should it not work for any image?

Comment: Yeah, i mean i doesn't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: do you want the image, filling the pseudo element?

Comment: @CharlesLavalard Hmm. There is an image. There is a red circle behind it (a pseudo). On the screen width set to 375px, I placed it (that pseudo) the way it's supposed to be placed on bigger screens, so to speak. Currently it just scales the wrong way. Moves and does the stuff I don't want it to be doing

Comment: _“I placed it (that pseudo) the way it's supposed to be”_ - and what _exactly_ is this “way it’s supposed to be”? We have not seen your image, so how are we supposed to know what you actually want to achieve here?

Comment: _"so how are we supposed to know"_ - Well, you are not. I was looking for a rule that makes it possible. No matter how _exactly_ are the elements placed. It should work for every instance, as I said

Comment: Can you make a reproduction of what you want in paint or something to show us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the pseudo element to scale, you'll need to use fluid units.
Note that the method below uses the css property `aspect-ratio`, [this property isn't fully supported yet](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio).

How do we achieve a responsive circle:

- use `%` instead of `em` for the `width` of the circle
- use `aspect-ratio: 1/1` to have the height equal to the width
- change `left` property
- add a `transform` to center the circle

```css
.image-box {
  position: relative;
}

.image-box::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 12.5%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    background: tomato;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.image-box__image {
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
    <img class="image-box__image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/400x300">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some other, non-experimental way to do it?

Comment: I guess you could also use `vw`, but it will bring it's own issues

Comment: So it's either this or that, those two ways. Right?

Comment: Those are the one I can think of with your actual markup, with a different markup you could also use the padding trick to have a perfect circle.